# Does XtUnit support performance testing?

Tags: java, xtunit

Does XtUnit support performance testing?

Comment: What sort of performance testing are you after? What do you want it to be able to do?

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is a kind of functional testing whereas performance testing is done to validate non-functional requirements.

See Wikipedia entry on [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and [software performance testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.jperf.org/.

There's a strong argument that performance, where critical, should be specified as a requirement and therefore tested along with other requirements.